# Xcode 8 Interface builder for device specific layout

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xcode8

Using Xcode 8 Interface Builder, is it possible to position elements differently for one specific device (iPhone 4s)? Only this device is too small for regular design, so product requirement is to re-arrange the buttons for iPhone 4s only.

I tried varying for trait, but it affects many devices simultaneously.

So far, I was only able to workaround this with code:

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height <= 480 {
    // iPhone 4s
} else {
    // other
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, no, it seems impossible to work on one specific device with Xcode 8.0 Interface Builder. Trait variations will only let you work with regular/compact height/width, so that's a max of four distinct groups of devices:

- rH rW
- rH cW
- cH rW
- cH cW

Comment: I'm fighting this exact situation myself. The main device I'm trying to handle nicely is the 4s as well.